# 302 status when copying data to another app in AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, http-status-code-302, remoteapi

I'm trying to use the "Copy to another app" feature of AppEngine and keep getting an error:

```
Fetch to http://datastore-admin.moo.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api failed with status 302
```

This is for a Java app but I followed the [instructions](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin.html) on setting up a default Python runtime.

I'm 95% sure it's an authentication issue and the call to remote_api is redirecting to the Google login page. Both apps use Google Apps as the authentication mechanism. I've also tried copying to and from a third app we have which uses Google Accounts for authentication.

Notes:

- The user account I log in with is an Owner on all three apps. It's a Google Apps account (if that wasn't obvious).
- I have a gmail account this is an Owner on all three apps as well. When I log in to the admin console with it, I don't see the datastore admin console at all when I click it.
- I'm able to use the remote_api just fine from the command-line after I enter my details
- Tried with both the Python remote_api built-in and the Java one.

I've found similar questions/blog posts about this, one of which required logging in from a browser, then manually submitting the ACSID cookie you get after that's done. Can't do that here, obviously.

Comment: Same problem. Did you ever find a fix?

Comment: I have the reverse case about visibility of Datastore Admin! I can see from my gmail accounts, but not from the Google Apps domain accounts!

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think I got this working.

I'll refer to the two appIDs as "source" and "dest".

To enable datastore admin (as you know) you need to upload a Python project with the app.yaml and appengine_config.py files as described in the docs.

Either I misread the docs or there is an error. The "appID" inthe .yaml should be the app ID you are uploading to to enable DS admin.

The other appID in the appengine_config file, specifically this line:
remoteapi_CUSTOM_ENVIRONMENT_AUTHENTICATION = (
    'HTTP_X_APPENGINE_INBOUND_APPID', ['appID'])

Should be the appID of the "source", ID the app id of where the data is coming from in the DS copy operation.

I think this line is what allows the source appID to be authenticated as having permissions to write to the "dest" app ID.

So, I changed that .py, uploaded again to my "dest" app ID. To be sure I made this dummy python app as default and left it as that.

Then on the source app ID I tried the DS copy again, and all the copy jobs were kicked off OK - so it seems to have fixed it.